# Efficiently Merging Nested Arrays in PHP While Preserving Unique Key-Value Pairs

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, performance, merge

I'm working on a PHP project where I need to frequently merge multiple nested arrays. The key point is that I want to preserve unique key-value pairs across the arrays, giving priority to values from later arrays in the merge sequence.

**Here's a simplified example:**

```php
$array1 = [
    'fruits' => [
        'apple' => 'red',
        'banana' => 'yellow'
    ],
    'numbers' => [1, 2]
];

$array2 = [
    'fruits' => [
        'orange' => 'orange',
        'apple' => 'green' // Should overwrite 'red'
    ],
];

$array3 = [
    'numbers' => [2, 3, 4], // Should extend with unique values only, not replace the whole subarray
    'colors' => ['blue', 'purple'] // New key should be added
];

// Desired Output:
$mergedArray = [
    'fruits' => [
        'apple' => 'green', 
        'banana' => 'yellow',
        'orange' => 'orange'
    ],
    'numbers' => [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'colors' => ['blue', 'purple']
];
```

**My Current Approach (inefficient for large arrays):**

```
PHP
function mergeNestedArraysInefficient($arrays) {
    $mergedArray = [];

    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                // Nested array - handle recursively
                if (!isset($mergedArray[$key])) {
                    $mergedArray[$key] = $value; 
                } else {
                    $mergedArray[$key] = mergeNestedArraysInefficient([$mergedArray[$key], $value]);
                }
            } else {
                // Simple value - overwrite if key exists
                $mergedArray[$key] = $value; 
            }
        }
    }

    return $mergedArray;
}
```

**Question:**

Can anyone suggest a more efficient and elegant solution for this type of array merging in PHP? Are there built-in functions or well-established patterns that handle this scenario effectively, especially when dealing with larger, more complex arrays?

Comment: If you have working code, you should probably post it on [codereview.se] so that it can be reviewed for potential optimizations.   ...oh, your code doesn't work: https://3v4l.org/ZOY32

Comment: Why shouldn't it be `'numbers' => [1, 2, 2, 3, 4],`? There is a conflict between your desired output and your English explanation of desired processing.  Do you only want unique values in indexed levels?

Comment: Can you please clarify your desired result so that I can uv your question?

Comment: @mickmackusa - unique values are indeed a requirement. Duplicated values should replace existing ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the first thing that I came up with.

1. Pass the separate arrays into your recursive function as separate parameters.
2. Receive the first array as the "master" array, then loop over the subsequent arrays and determine the best course of action case-by-case.
3. If a level of data in an iterated array is an indexed array, then merely merge the values between the two arrays, removed duplicates and re-index.  If not an indexed array, then make key-based declarations (potentially recursively).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8a37r))

```
function mergeRecursively(array $array, array ...$otherArrays) {
    foreach ($otherArrays as $other) {
        if (array_is_list($other)) {
            $array = array_values(array_unique(array_merge($array, $other)));
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($other as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v) && key_exists($k, $array)) {
                $array[$k] = mergeRecursively($array[$k], $v);
            } else {
                $array[$k] = $v; 
            }
        }
    }

    return $array;
}

var_export(mergeRecursively($array1, $array2, $array3));
```

I don't know if this still provides a performance problem, but it correctly processes the data as you've described.